# Publish rc2 asp.net core application to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I managed to publish my application from VSO to Windows Azure. The problem now is that my application fail to start on Azure with this error (it works perfectly locally) :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis.get_IsWindows()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at MyApp.Web.Startup.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis..cctor()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I tried to add the dependency manually but it didn't solve the problem :

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0-rc2-23826"
```

Here is my config

global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test", "lib" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc2-20221",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

project.json

```
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Jil": "2.13.0",
    "JWT": "1.3.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-20270",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.Dnx": "1.0.0-rc2-20221",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0-rc2-23826"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  }
```

Comment: What steps did you use to publish? Did you use FTP?

Comment: Yes, I published using FTP, I changed web.cmd to point directly to the runtime folder ( which i copy manually into the artifact because I don't use the parameter --runtime active, if I use this parameter the dnu publish fail )

Comment: Have you tried hosting locally with IIS? I ask because Azure uses IIS under the covers, and if we make it work locally with IIS, then we can publish the same stuff to Azure, and be quite sure that it will work.

Comment: using IisExpress it works, I haven't tried IIS.

Comment: Ok I'll try IIS, but I think that even if it works, it wouldn't tell us what's wrong the things in azure, I'll try it and tell you.

Comment: Azure uses IIS behind the scenes. So, if it works in IIS then it's likely to work in Azure. Testing your publish locally in IIS is a good litmus test for determining whether it will work in Azure, because it takes a fraction of a time to test locally than it does to publish the approx 50 MB app to Azure.

Comment: In IIS it seems to work ( it goes beyond the startup so it doesn't hit the same problem ). It's easier to test on IIS, I'll make some more verifications tomorrow ( it's 1:36am here in Paris), thanks you very much for your help,

Comment: Try to change the .Net Framework to 4.5 & redeploy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Test Locally on IIS

Azure uses IIS under the covers. If the app works in IIS, it will usually work in an Azure Web App. The official docs have [clear instructions for publishing to IIS](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). Once it works in IIS, deploy the same stuff to Azure.

## RC2 Azure Publish Walk-thru

Here are the exact publish steps that work for me. I made a sample that uses the project.json from your question and [pushed the sample to GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/RuntimeInfo).

Clone the sample:

```
C:\> git clone https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow.git
C:\> cd .\StackOverflow\RuntimeInfo
```

Then publish the project:

```
C:\StackOverflow\RuntimeInfo> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc2-20221 -runtime clr
C:\StackOverflow\RuntimeInfo> dotnet restore
C:\StackOverflow\RuntimeInfo> dotnet publish -c Release -o ./approot
```

Those commands target the RC2 runtime, restore the NuGet packages, and publish a release configuration to the approot directory. This is the result:

```
C:\StackOverflow\RuntimeInfo> dir
approot            
bin                
obj                            
Program.cs         
project.json       
project.lock.json     
wwwroot
```

Now, using FTP, publish the `approot` and `wwwroot` directories to Azure's `site` directory.

```
./site
    approot
    wwwroot
```

This is the result in Azure.

[image: Use of the System.Runtime.InteropServices in Azure]

## A Final Note

Be careful "crossing the streams." Your app has two release versions in its project.json/global.json files: 1.0.0-rc2-20221 and 1.0.0-rc2-20270. It is probably better to choose one.

Comment: The local test on IIS was very helpful, I'll accept this answer because it's very interesting, my problem was that when I changed the web.cmd manually, I fixed the version of my application package so when I published new versions, It was always using the old version which has the issue. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @yeska Aha. Yes. That would have been a problem. Nicely done finding the fix and thank you for accepting the answer. Could you please up-vote it also. I would appreciate that. :)